# Issue with image resizing on mobile (PHP)

Tags: image, mobile, resize

i am currently inserting css coding to make my site (PHP) mobile responsive for a mobile phone.  The problem i am encountering is when wanting to reduce the size of an image to 50% on both height and width. it does not resize the image... ?  Below is the code for the image and the css section for my mobile settings:

```
HTML

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
scale=1.0">

<div class="logo">
   <img src="./img/newlogo.png" alt="logo" />
</div>

CSS code:

@media only screen and (max-width: 736px){
  .logo{
    position:absolute;
    top:2%;
    left:10%;
    Width:50%;
    Height:50%
  }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Move your logo class on image

```
<div>
   <img class="logo" src="./img/newlogo.png" alt="logo" />
</div>
```

Comment: Great ! works now. , Thanks Jubair, much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome @Alex  You can marked as answer it's will more appreciate for me

Comment: Will do , Thanks Jubair